# List all the dependencies of a SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm working in a legacy system that has a lot of views. Each view depends on other views, which depends on other views... It is not unusual to add a new join and hit the max number of tables allowed in a query. I'd like to find the greatest offenders.

How do I recursively list all the database objects that a view depends on? If the object depends on other objects I also would like to list them. Bonus points if I also can tell how deep is the dependency tree. A solution that I can run from command line is best, since I plan to someday run it in a continuous integration server.

I'm using SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
select distinct so.name,so.xtype
from sysdepends sd
join sysobjects so on sd.depid=so.id
where sd.id=object_id('<your view name here>')
```

Should work in SQL 2000, but I haven't used that version in a while

Comment: A warning: [sysdepends isn't reliable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115333#appliesto).

Comment: SysDepends is not recommended, I agree, but he is using SQL 2000.